# Reading lines from file with "for" command only executes once

Tags: command-line, batch

I'm trying to read multiple lines from a text file and send them to another batch file like so -

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (files.txt) do (
call go.bat "%%~a"
)
```

Here is go.bat -

```
echo %1 >> data.txt
```

I have 2 lines in files.txt but only the first is read. How do I read multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, had an "exit' command at the end of go.bat!